# Why is it outputting a comma between values?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

**UPDATED SQL:**

```
SELECT listTitle, listLength, listCmt, listDt,GROUP_CONCAT('',mBCFName,' ',mBCLName,' ',moAmt,'<BR>') AS mOfferInfo
FROM User U
INNER JOIN Listing L on (U.uID = L.uID)
INNER JOIN MerchantOffer MO ON (L.listID = MO.listID)
INNER JOIN Merchant M on (M.mID = MO.mId) 
GROUP BY listTitle
ORDER BY listDt DESC
```

**How do I make this code output ?? :**

```
Title: Apple iPhone 4S
Comment: need this one quick!

15257 days 22 hours ago
Offer By: 
Diana Matthews 194.99
John Dickinson 185.99
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

> The default separator between values in a group is comma (“,”).

If you don't want the comma, change it to something else:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(' ',mBCFName,' ',mBCLName,' ',moAmt,'<br />' SEPARATOR '')
```

or you could just use the `<br />` as the separator:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(' ',mBCFName,' ',mBCLName,' ',moAmt SEPARATOR '<br />')
```

Comment: How do I modify this to ONLY be during certain values?

Comment: Please see updated sql, by changing the `' ' ` to `''` it didnt change anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please actually read my post; changing `' '` to `''` in your query isn't what you need to do - you need to add the `SEPARATOR ''` part.

Answer (score 1):

There's a default seperator between the concatenated values. Have a look at [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) description. To "disable" the `,` between the values you must use `SEPARATOR ''`.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL, change:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(' ',mBCFName,' ',mBCLName,' ',moAmt,'<br />')
```

to:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(mBCFName,' ',mBCLName,' ',moAmt,'<br />')
```